# How to perform a unit-test on a socket value?

Tags: c, unit-testing, sockets, server

I have a project to create an FTP server (and soon a client) in C.

To make matters worse, I want to apply the TDD methods during the project.
Also I would like to know how to check the validity of a socket?

To perform my tests, I am using [Check](https://github.com/libcheck/check) framework.

```
#include "server.h"

START_TEST(test_create_server)
{
    int     socket;
    int     port;

    port = 80;
    socket = create_server(port); // will in fact call socket()
    // function that should test socket validity
    close(socket);
}
END_TEST

int     main(void)
{
    return (0);
}
```

I read that getsockopt() could be a possible solution but really, I don't get the optname, optval and optlen values. Should I have already a client to test it ? I would rather go for a simple but effective solution.

Thank you all!

Comment: What do you mean by "socket validity"? What does the `create_server` return on failure? Maybe that's what you should test against?

Comment: I'd like to think of this more as an _integration_ test problem than a unit test problem, your unit tests should be what many consider _pure_ and not interact with IO. You can later create integration tests that interact with those system functionalities, but your best bet would be make sure your abstractions are perhaps easily mockable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. For what I understood so far, a socket is just some kind of file descriptor. I want to check that it could be a 'viable' one. But I understand that my question is might be wrong. create_server is just an abstraction layer that will call socket() system call. Maybe I should just test errno on it.

Comment: @jacob. I am very new to TDD. I thought unit-testing was only about input/output. To check what goes into a function and what goes out of it. How can I test a function in a unit test kind of way without IO interaction ? If an answer to that question is too long do you have some documentation I could read ? Sorry for my english, I am not a native speaker btw.

Comment: No, the value of `errno` is undefined unless the previous function is documented as setting it. And for the `socket` system call `errno` is only set in case of failure (when `socket` returns `-1`). Don't check `errno` unless `socket` have returned `-1`.

Comment: Also, unit-testing works best when you test deterministic "input". Typically, testing `socket` (or thin wrappers around it) is only useful if you can do it in a deterministic way, and know when it will fail and when it will not beforehand.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. Ok, so do you have some advice to design a deterministic test for `socket` ? I thought mine could be one, but apparently it's not. If this question is too long to answer, feel free to recommend me some documentation. And thx already for your replies